# Testing for input accuracy using a scanner with while and nested if/else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

So I am trying to use a while loop to continue asking for input while the user's input of a random number does not equal the random number generator's output. However when I input the number the higher/lower outputs do not work. It either always says its higher or always says its lower, regardless of the actual numerical value. Help?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static final int MAX = 100;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rand1 = rand.nextInt(MAX);
        introduction();
        game(scan, rand1);
    }
    public static void introduction() {
        System.out.println("This program allows you to play a guessing game."     
            " I will think of a number between 1 and" +
            " 100 and will allow you to guess until" +
            " you get it.  For each guess, I will tell you" +
            " whether the right answer is higher or lower" +
            " than your guess");
    }
    public static void game(Scanner scan, int rand1) {
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100...");
        System.out.println(rand1);
        System.out.println("Your guess?");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        while(input != rand1) {
            if (input < rand1) {
                System.out.println("It's higher");
                scan.nextInt(input);
            }
            else if (input > rand1) {
                System.out.println("It's lower");
                scan.nextInt(input);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the javadoc of the method you're using to read the next int and change the value of input inside the loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt-int-. Does that look like what you want to do? You're doing it right the first time. Why don't you do it the same inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The input value you type in at the beginning doesn't change whatever you type in later. 
Solution: 
You need to use `input = scan.nextInt();`
          instead of `scan.nextInt(input);`!

Hope i helped! :)